# How to access my own database using Neo4j browser

Tags: database, neo4j

I have a Neo4j database called `shopx.db`, I moved it into `/var/lib/neo4j/data/database` then I edited the `dbms.active_database=graph.dp` to `dbms.active_database=shopx.db` in the`neo4j.conf` file.

Now when I am running the service and opening the site I am expecting to see the `shopx.db` running in the browser but instead I can't reach the site, so what exactly should I do to be able to access `shopx.db` using Neo4j browser?

I am sorry if the question seems naive but I am new to Neo4j.

Comment: can you check the logs of neo4j (neo4j.log & debug.log) ?

Comment: Here is what I found https://imgur.com/ufHUGSE

Comment: this is just the first part of the log, and sadly what I want to see is mainly the end of the file to see if there are some errors ...

Comment: Oh ok, here is the whole file https://drive.google.com/file/d/10jjqc7_57hi2CC_Kqsre-ODSacU2I5m_/view?usp=sharing

Comment: So the config is good, and the server seems to start ... You have not acces to `http:///localhost:7474` ?

Comment: Yeah when I am trying to access it saying localhost refused to connect.